# Problem with making random seed work in python

Tags: python, random-seed

I am generating random entries at selected positions in a matrix and I would like to see the same entries over different runs of the code. So I did the following but I'm not sure what I did wrong to get different entries on each run?

```
import numpy as np
import random
random.seed(10)

N = 5
G = [[0 for i in np.arange(N)] for j in np.arange(N)]
for i in np.arange(N):
    for j in np.arange(N):
        if i==j:
            G[i][j] = 0
        else:
            if abs(i-j) <= 2:
                random.seed(10)
                G[i][j] = round(np.random.uniform(0,1),2)
            else:
                G[i][j] = 0

print(G)
```

Comment: You set the seed for Python's `random` package, but you called NumPy's RNG instead.  You didn't touch that seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace

```
random.seed(10)
```

by

```
np.random.seed(10)
```

to have a fixed random state. Since you use NumPy's `random` module to generate the random number, you ought to use `np.random.seed()` to fix the random state. That is how I understood it.